# Make XMLHttpRequest synchronous when "async" option is true?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, callback

The signature of the `open` method of `XMLHttpRequest` looks like this:

```
void open(DOMString method, DOMString url, optional boolean async, optional DOMString? user, optional DOMString? password);
```

The third parameter of `open` is `async`. When set to false, the XMLHttpRequest object becomes synchronous, which means it will **block** the executing process until the request if finished.

I was wondering whether I can write a (wrapper) function `getUrlSync(String url)` if the `async` option is set to `true`. If so, this might be a general approach to convert an Asynchronous API into a Synchronous one.

I know forcing a async API to be sync is awful, but I was just curious whether it is possible..

I don't think it is simple to do that. To check whether the HTTP request is finished, a polling is need within a `while` loop. But as Javascript is in a **single-thread** environment, the intepreter will seem to be **stuck** in the `while` loop forever and never do the **deferred** HTTP request.. Does that make sense?

Does anyone have any ideas about this?

Comment: why not just make a function that calls open() with "false" and another one that does it with "true" as a value for the 3rd parameter?

Comment: If you wanted something to be synchronous (which you wouldn't, its awful, and deprecated for a reason), why wouldn't you just call `open` with `false` in the first place?

Comment: @Quentin I mean the API doesn't provide a synchronous version..

Comment: if it is possible, then why do browsers provide an extra flag for `sync` requests?

Comment: @hanfeisun — Of course the XHR API provides a synchronous version, you've described how to activate it in the question.